# Find records with multiple foreign key values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've got two models **User** and **Post** where a 
`:user` `has_many :posts`

How do I find a list of users who have more than `n` posts?

I'm looking for a simple statement like `where` rather than something to do with using scopes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `where` query does not allow aggregate functions like count inside it, the ideal method to tackle this problem is using the `having` method.

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').having('COUNT(*) >= ?', n)
```

This will be mapped to

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= n
```

There is another method possible which is more easier, by using counter cache inside the Post Model and keeping the count as a posts_count column on the user table.

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache:true 
User.where('posts_count > ?', n)
```

But I prefer the first method as it does not involve any DB changes and is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 1):

```
User.join(:posts).group('users.id').having('count(user_id) > n')
```

Another way of solving this is to use counter_cache and add a posts_count column on the user table.

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache:true # Inside the Post model
```

Then you can do

```
User.where('posts_count > ?', n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let try this:

```
User.where('id IN (SELECT user_id 
                   FROM posts
                   GROUP BY user_id
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > ?
                  )', n)
```